# Calling .exe from VBA, but the program does not run correctly

Tags: python, vba, outlook, exe

I wrote a python to script to scrape a table of data from a website and output to a csv. I then used cx_freeze to convert the python script to a .exe. When I run the .exe manually, it performs as expected, however, when i run the code below from outlook, the csv is never created. No errors pop up either.

```
Dim wsh As Object, x As Integer
Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
x = wsh.Run("cmd /c C:\Users\username\Desktop\Lindner_Scrape\build\exe.win32-3.6\Scrape.exe", 1, True)
```

Comment: Check that it's not present in your documents. Try to change the working dir in Excel or use relative path in your python script.

Comment: It it's not raising an error, then the file *is* being created, you just haven't figured out where it's being written. Show contents of your .py file and that may help identify the source of your problem...

Comment: Florent solved it. It is saving to my documents (when running manually saves in the current directory).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a batch file. Write your commands in it and execute batch file.

```
Sub bat()
Dim batch, fso As Object
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\Lindner_Scrape\build\exe.win32-3.6\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set batch = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "Scrape.bat", True)
batch.writeline "cd " & path
batch.writeline "Scrape.exe"
batch.Close

Shell path & "Scrape.bat", 1
End Sub
```